# how to use file object as argument in Popen string (the file is only a variable, not an actual file)

Tags: python, bash, file, pipe, stdout

Im converting some of my bash scripts to python, and the scripts were mostly used to run command line tools.

I realise Popen is the recomended way to go, but I get errors if I try the method described below, so could please someone xplain it to me on this simple example.

bash code:

```
varA = 50
command1 > file.foo
echo $varA | command2 file.foo
```

python code:

```
varA=50
com1 = Popen('command1',stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
com1out = com1.stdout  #NOTE com1out is of 'file' type

com2 = Popen('command2  %s' % com1out),stdin=varA, stdout=PIPE)
```

Comment: Where does `cmdOconv` come from?

Comment: what kind of error do you get

Comment: How does `cat varA | command2 file.foo` work?  Do you have a file called `varA`?  If you used `cat $varA` then you would need a file called `50`.

Comment: cmdOconv was typo, and y. instead of cat, echo varA. my bad.

Comment: error: fatal - command line error at '<open'

Comment: `echo varA` or `echo $varA`?

Comment: shouldnt make a difference in this case, varA, and 50, but for the sake of this example $varA

Answer (score 0):

The shell code

```
command1 > file.foo
echo $varA | command2 file.foo
```

uses a regular file `file.foo`, and `command2` expects the name of such a file as an argument, so the straight translation to Python is:

```
from subprocess import *
call('command1', stdout=open('file.foo', 'w'))
Popen(['command2', 'file.foo'], stdin=PIPE).communicate(str(varA)+'\n')
```